# What's the meaning of noun + to + verb?

Tags: meaning, verbs, headline-english

I can't understand, what does the following sentence mean and other similar sentences: (for example)

> France to ban street scooters in Paris.

What does it mean, if we use "to" after the noun and before a verb? I know, that there is form "somebody is to do something", but at the same time I don't understand a "noun + to + verb" form.

Comment: Consider that it is a newspaper title where they generally need to save space.  *France is considering to ban…*

Comment: It is approximately the same as "France will ban street scooters in Paris." I think there is a subtle difference is meaning, but I don't know how to explain it.

Comment: @MichaelHardy If there's a difference it must be really subtle, I can't think of it.

Comment: Omitting verbs like this is common in "headlinese". "noun to verb" is short for "noun is going to verb"

Comment: _Ellipsis_ is the term when words are omitted in a sentence. News headlines often use ellipsis for brevity.

Comment: @Barmar : I think the version with "to" means this is intended, whereas the one with "will" only means that it will happen.

Comment: @MichaelHardy When talking about the government, you can't really count on it until it actually happens.

Comment: @Barmar : Nonetheless, I think that's what the two ways of expressing it mean.